# How get the index of element

Tags: python, selenium, search, indexing, element

How can I get the index of the typed keyword in the search text box that appears in the search suggestion list to verify that typed keyboard is the first element that appears in the suggestion list or not?

```
 def test_get_index(self):
       try:
           Search_text_Box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/label/input")
           Search_text_Box.send_keys("erferf")
           Search_text_Box.click()
           time.sleep(3)
           allelements=self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody")

           for Arrow in allelements:
              required_index_of_element=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]"). get_attribute("index")
              print (required_index_of_element)
              Expected_Index= "1"
              self.assertEqual(required_index_of_element,Expected_Index, "This Test case is failled because the typed keword should be the first appear in search results")
       except NoSuchElementException as e:
             print (e)
       except TimeoutException as e:
             print (e)
```

I use `get_attribute("index")` to get the arrangement of the typed keyword in the search suggestion list to verify if the typed keyword is the first element that appears in the search suggestion list or not. But the result I get always (`None`). Is this method that I use right, if yes why I get `None` always in the result? Is there are other methods to print the index of the element that is in the search suggestion list?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML for the INPUT your are referring to as well as the HTML for the dropdown containing suggestions. Also, a link to the page would really help visualize the problem.